# Rails custom validate - uniqueness of a property across models

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm stuck at defining a custom validation method that's purpose is to verify uniqueness of a property across two models

I realize this is bad code, but i wanted to get the test passing before refactor

here is a model with the custom validation to check another model property, error undefined local variable or method `params'  (be gentle I'm still trying to figure out RoR)

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Slugable
  validates :name, presence: true
  validate :uniqueness_of_a_slug_across_models

  def uniqueness_of_a_slug_across_models
    @sprocket = Sprocket.where(slug: params[:widget_slug]).first
    if @sprocket.present?
      errors.add(:uniqueness_of_a_slug_across_models, "can't be shared slug")
    end
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't have access to `params` in a model. It belongs to controller and view. What you could do is to call custom method in widgets controller (instead of regular `save`) in order to pass params to a model:

```
class WidgetsController < ActionController::Base
  def create
    @widget = Widget.new(widget_params)

    if @widget.save_with_slug_validation(params)
      redirect_to widgets_path
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```

and define it:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...

  def save_with_slug_validation(params)
    sprocket = Sprocket.find_by(slug: params[:widget_slug])

    if sprocket
      errors.add(:uniqueness_of_a_slug_across_models, "can't be shared slug")
    end

    save
  end

end
```

I didn't test it but it should work.

P.S. Rails 4 style is used.

## UPD

I should have tested it, sorry. Please use another approach.

**Widgets controller:**

```
# POST /widgets
# POST /widgets.json
def create
  @widget = widget.new(widget_params)
  @widget.has_sprocket! if Sprocket.find_by(slug: params[:widget_slug])

  respond_to do |format|
    if @widget.save
      format.html { redirect_to [:admin, @widget], notice: 'widget was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @widget }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'new' }
      format.json { render json: @widget.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

**Widget model:**

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Slugable

  validates :name, presence: true
  validate :uniqueness_of_a_slug_across_models, if: 'has_sprocket?'
 
  def uniqueness_of_a_slug_across_models
    errors.add(:uniqueness_of_a_slug_across_models, "can't be shared slug")
  end

  def has_sprocket!
    @has_sprocket = true
  end

  def has_sprocket?
    !!@has_sprocket
  end

end
```

It would be better to move `has_sprocket!` and `has_sprocket?` methods and maybe validation itself to `Slugable` concern.

Comment: I notice that you took out the validate :uniqueness_of_a_slug_across_models line, I implemented as you described but no validation, by putting that line back in i get an undefined local variable error for uniqueness_of_a...

Comment: Let me know if you have any issues.

Comment: i made all of the changes, i get no error but no validation either, i updated my gist with the code changes, and included the slugable concern in case https://gist.github.com/Jrizzi1/9665655

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50161/discussion-between-peresleguine-and-jay-rizzi)